# Unable to bind field of type int in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to save data in database but the problem i'm facing is that Every data of fields is binding with model except integer type fields it bind 0 to them.

I gives value in the fields but instead of those value it bind 0 to them.

Can anyone help me with this that how do i solve this problem.

This is the View about which i'm facing the problem.

The Fields which are not binding is Adult,Children,Senior and Travelers

```
@model Airline.Models.BookingModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Buy";
}


<h2>Buy</h2>

<h4>BookingModel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Buy">

            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input asp-for="FlightSkyMiles" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.Flight.SkyMiles" />


            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FlightName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FlightName" value="@ViewBag.Flight.FlightName" class="form-control" readonly />
                <span asp-validation-for="FlightName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FlightNo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FlightNo" value="@ViewBag.Flight.FlightNo" class="form-control" readonly />
                <span asp-validation-for="FlightNo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="OriginCity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="OriginCity" value="@ViewBag.Flight.OriginCity" class="form-control" readonly />
                <span asp-validation-for="OriginCity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DestinationCity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DestinationCity" value="@ViewBag.Flight.DestinationCity" class="form-control" readonly />
                <span asp-validation-for="DestinationCity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Departure" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Departure" type="datetime" value="@ViewBag.Flight.Departure" class="form-control" readonly />
                <span asp-validation-for="Departure" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Adult" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Adult" type="number" name="seats" value="0" class="form-control" id="adult" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Adult" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Children" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Children" type="number"  name="seats" value="0" class="form-control" id="childern" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Children" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Senior" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Senior" type="number"  name="seats" value="0" class="form-control" id="senior" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Senior" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Travelers" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Travelers" type="number" name="TotalSeats" class="form-control" id="total" readonly required />
                <span asp-validation-for="Travelers" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FlightClass" class="control-label"></label>
                <select class="form-control" onchange="getPrice(@ViewBag.Flight.Id)" asp-for="FlightClass" id="fclass" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Classtype>()" itemid="" required>
                    <option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="FlightClass" class="text-danger"></span>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Price" onchange="multPrice()" id="price" class="form-control" readonly />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="radio" name="Reservation" value="Buy" required /> &nbsp;Buy &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="Reservation" value="Block" /> &nbsp;Block
                <span asp-validation-for="ReservationType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            function calculate() {
                var adult = parseInt($("#adult").val());
                var chi = parseInt($("#childern").val());
                var sen = parseInt($("#senior").val());
                $("#total").val(adult + chi + sen);
            };
            $("#adult").keyup(calculate);
            $("#childern").keyup(calculate);
            $("#senior").keyup(calculate);





        });




    </script>
}
    <script>
        function getPrice(id) {

            function multPrice()
            {
                var mult = $("#total").val() * $("#price").val();
                $("#price").val(mult);
            }


            $.ajax
                ({
                    url: '/Home/getPrice',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: { id:id,classId: $("#fclass").val()},
                    success: function (result) {

                        $("#price").val(result.price);
                        multPrice();
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error")
                    }
                });

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: You're changing the name value (i.e. `name="TotalSeats"`) - do you understand how HTML forms work? Is there a reason you're using ViewBag for everything when you have a strongly-typed model for your view?

Comment: i'm using viewbag because  i'm populating some fields from another model but i'm not able to use @model for other model that's why i used viewbag

Comment: Thank you sir for you help 
it's mean that name tag can disturb the binding with model

Comment: any way thanks again . I have tried it and now it's working fine

Comment: The value of a form control's `name` attribute is the "key" used to submit the control's value. You can see this by using your browser's developer tools and observing the Network tab.

Comment: Try Int32.Parse(yourComingNumberRequest) and after that save it.